# Keycloak login with mobile number and otp Rest api (Direct Grant)

Tags: oauth, authorization, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I am migrating from spring security oauth to keycloak. My current system supports login with username/password, mobile number/password and moobile number/otp.

Keycloak allows me login and generate token using username/password and mobile number/password using custom provider SPI implementation.

I want to allow my users to login with OTP. In my current implementation I am using grant_type. If grant_type is 'password' we check for username and password. If grant_type is otp, We send an otp to mobile number and secret against otp to frontend for validation. We then receive otp with secret and if it is valid, token is generated for user.

Keycloak is allowing to create auth for browser flow but not for direct grant or rest api. Is there any possible solution for this using keycloak?